# How to read column from csv and run a update query?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a csv file that has 6000 rows of dates and ID numbers. I'm using SQL Oracle Developer. I've uploaded my CSV file into Oracle.

The CSV file table is `table3`. I want to update `table1` with the following query. As mentioned in `table3` (CSV file) has 6000 `T1_ID`. I want it to go through the csv file and get the `T1_ID` and update `table1`.

Since there are bunch of dates in my CSV file, I'm thinking maybe using dates would be an better option to get the `T1_ID`s.

```
update table1
set RESULT_CODE = 62
where T1_ID = ? 
CREATED_time >= ?
and CREATED_time <= ?
```

This is an example of what the table 3 looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a MERGE statement:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 t1
  USING (SELECT *
           FROM TABLE3) t3
    ON (t1.ID = t3.ID AND
        t3.CREATED_TIME BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('01-APR-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                            AND TO_TIMESTAMP('02-MAY-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY') - INTERVAL '0.000000001' SECOND)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t1.RESULT_CODE = 62;
```

Comment: This is a good idea but table 1 is huge and I don't want to merge these tables. I just want use the update query and use the reference ID from the CSV and time stamp.

Comment: `MERGE` is Oracle's term for an upsert (combined update and insert) operation. Here there's no need for the "insert" part of the statement so I've simply left it out. I just find that sometimes it's easier to read and understand a MERGE than an UPDATE with a subquery.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. So this will update and insert. For the time stamp. I want it between the timestamp I've provided. How would I make it so that it stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like

```
update table1 a set
  a.result_code = 62
  where exists (select null 
                from table3 b
                where b.t1_id = a.t1_id
                  and b.created_time between to_timestamp('01.05.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
                                         and to_timestamp('10.05.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
               );
```

Comment: Why are we selecting null from table 3

Comment: It doesn't matter *what* it returns; EXISTS is interested only in existence of at least one row that satisfies the condition.

Comment: Also the created time is the same column and format in both tables. I'm confused why this column is there. ('10.05.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy') When I just want to use the same time.

Comment: Then your example doesn't make sense. If something is >= CREATED_DATE and - at the same time - <= CREATED_DATE, then it is **equal** to CREATED_DATE. Basically, I tried to guess what you wanted as - honestly - you didn't provide much info about description nor contents of tables involved.

Comment: Sorry about that. > = Apr 1 and <= May 1. So everything in between those dates.

Comment: OK, so change values I used as example with yours.